# Selenium does not locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

I am a newbie to Python. I have written a code to automatically login to the website, https://www.quora.com. The issue is, selenium loads up Firefox perfectly, but then the program does not proceed further. That is, it does not go on to enter my email and password.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.quora.com')

browser.implicitly_wait(30)

email = browser.find_element_by_class_name('email')

pw = browser.find_element_by_class_name('password')

email.send_keys('my_email')
pw.send_keys('my_password')
pw.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I have written a similar program to automate login into Gmail, which works perfectly. The code is given below, although it is almost exactly the same as the above.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://www.gmail.com')

browser.implicitly_wait(10)

email = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')

email.send_keys('my_username')

email.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

pw = browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd')

pw.send_keys('my_password')

pw.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Both programs use the implicit wait method, that is, the program waits for a specified time interval for the page to load, followed by which it throws an exception.

I have also tried the explicit wait method, mentioned in the selenium documentation http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html. Gmail login works with that method too, but Quora login does not.

Why does this happen? And how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Although Shubham Jain's answer is ok, Quora changes their ID's and classes for everything very often.  They are notoriously hard to scrape or do anything with.  This is by design.

So if you plan on doing any scraping on Quora(I will advise you this is against their terms of service), I would do my best to never use Classes or ID's for targeting anything on their webpage!

If I were you I would try and search by things that do not change like you tried to do!  You were actually fairly close!

Instead of:

> email = browser.find_element_by_class_name('email')

Do

> email = browser.find_element_by_name('email')

You'll notice that you were looking by "class_name" and what you really wanted was just "name".

Same thing with your password!

> pw = browser.find_element_by_class_name('password')

Do

> pw = browser.find_element_by_name('password')

Sometimes these naming conventions can get confusing, I would highly recommend getting good at searching with Xpath.

Comment: Thanks @Morgan G, that is a something I should have paid attention to. However, I replaced class_name with name like you said, but it still does not solve the problem! Do you think that since this is against Quora's terms of service (as you said, which I did not know), then could they somehow have disabled all attempts of scraping at their website?

Comment: Also, how did you know whether to use 'name' or 'class name'? By looking at the source code of the page I saw this: <input class="text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction" group="__w2_D57FkOu_interaction" placeholder="Email" name="email" tabindex="1" w2cid="D57FkOu" id="__w2_D57FkOu_email" type="text">                                                                                                               I used to think that whichever attribute is defined inside the <> is always a css class. So I assume now that this is wrong? And what's the difference between 'class name' and name?

Comment: "(vi) access or search or attempt to access or search the Service by any means (automated or otherwise) other than through the currently available, published interfaces that are provided by Quora (and only pursuant to those terms and conditions), unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Quora (crawling the Service is permissible in accordance with these Terms, but scraping the Service without the prior consent of Quora except as permitted by these Terms is expressly prohibited);"

Comment: @JamesBond `<input class="text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction" group="__w2_mBPtzGo_interaction" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" tabindex="1" w2cid="mBPtzGo" id="__w2_mBPtzGo_email">`  is a carbon copy of the login input, if you see there is a name element of "email".  I don't know of any site that can disable scraping but that would be a million dollar idea if someone could figure it out.  The best they can do is make it very hard.  Does your application type in your email and password, and stall on submitting them?  It could be a problem with `pw.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

Comment: OK, I got the name element part. Can you think of an example where you have to use 'class name'? That would make things very clear. Also, my program stalls just after loading up the website. That is, Firefox opens, Quora loads up and then the program does nothing. BTW, I am thinking of scrapping (with a double p :D ) the entire project as it is against the terms of service :(

Answer (score 0):

Your id for email input is not `Email` but `__w2_XYMxo3M_email`

Your id for password input is not `Passwd` but `__w2_XYMxo3M_password`

Your element `name` is `Email` and `Passwd` for field respectively

Try with it.

Comment: I have searched for the elements using the 'name' attribute, not the id. I have used the id only in the Gmail login.

Comment: email = browser.find_element_by_class_name('email')

pw = browser.find_element_by_class_name('password')

Comment: <input id="__w2_XYMxo3M_email" class="text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction" type="text" w2cid="XYMxo3M" tabindex="1" name="email" placeholder="Email" group="__w2_XYMxo3M_interaction"/>

Comment: class="text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction"